# How to align a search icon inside a search box

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to align a search icon, within the text box, same as Google's search bar

**Like this:**

[image]

This is what i got, but idk How to do it:

[image]

I am trying to avoid using bootstrap or any library. I want to keep it vanilla as much as I can.

```css
#search-bar {
  width: 32%;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  height: 44px;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-bar-form">
  <input id="search-bar" type="text" href="#" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/24" />
</form>
```

Comment: mabye switching your styled textbox for a div, then styling it like you did with textbox, adding the image inside and next to it the textbox would be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the image as the background of the textbox:

```css
#search-bar {
  width: 32%;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  height: 44px;
  
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/24);
  background-position: 10px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-bar-form">
  <input id="search-bar" type="text" value="text goes after the padding" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position: absolute.
Like this:

```
form {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: abosolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

You should update top and right values.
This is only example.

Comment: You'd need to position the _input_ relatively, and you wouldn't want to apply absolute position to _all_ images. You should copy the snippet down here and edit to show your solution.

Comment: Don't you want to use position: absolute ?

Comment: I see. You are super.

Comment: And then If you want to not use absolute, I can help you.

Comment: You can align input and img tag inside Div

Answer (score 0):

Add some `padding-left` to the search bar, to move the text more to the right side.

Then add a class to the image and define it like that:

```
.mySearchIconImage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
```

Also add `position: relative` to the form itself, to make sure the `img` isn't positioned outside of your form.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways. One way is with absolute position inside a relative position parent...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#search-bar {
  width: 32%;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  height: 44px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 44px;
}

.search-icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-bar-form">
    <input id="search-bar" type="text" href="#" />
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/50/000000/search.png" class="search-icon" />
</form>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/RB46wV9Oan)

---

Another way is using relative position and a negative margin. For this, put the img before the input in your markup.

```css
#search-bar {
  width: 32%;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  height: 44px;
  padding-left: 44px;
}

.search-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -60px;
  z-index: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<form class="search-bar-form">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/50/000000/search.png" class="search-icon" />
    <input id="search-bar" type="text" href="#" />
</form>
```